# Non convergent simple continued fractions?

Tags: continued-fractions

Let $<a_0;a_1,a_2,\dots>$ be an infinite sequence of integers such that
$$0<n\implies a_n>0.$$

For any natural $n$ we know there exists a *convergent*: one rational number $r_n$ such that it is equal to the [simple continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleContinuedFraction.html)
$$r_n=a_0+\frac{1}{a_1 +\frac{1}{a_2 +\frac{1}{\ddots_{a_n+0}}}}$$
$r_n$ is the number given by the finite continued fraction of the original sequence truncated at $n$, $<a_0;a_1,a_2,\dotsm,a_n>$.

The question is: given *any* sequence of positive integers, does the simple continued fraction always converge to a real number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, an even better theorem is available, the *Seidel-Stern theorem*.  Let $\langle a_i\rangle$ be any sequence of positive real numbers.  Then the continued fraction $[a_0; a_1, a_2, \ldots]$ converges if and only if the series $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i$$ *diverges*!

By restricting the $a_i$ to be positive integers, we get the answer to your question: all such continued fractions converge.

(This is theorem 10 (p.10–12) in *Continued Fractions*, A. Ya. Khinchin, Phoenix Science Press 1964, or theorem 9.31 (p.185) in *Neverending Fractions: An Introduction to Continued Fractions* by Borwein et al., Cambridge University Press 2014.)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the [Continued Fraction Limit](https://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node65.html) (See Theorem 5.2).

The answer is: *yes*!